# MediaWiki Integration

Tags: php, mediawiki, usercake

Is there any way that I can integrate the [UserCake](http://www.usercake.com/) user management system with MediaWiki?  I want to link the accounts in each system so users can log into both with the same username and password.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no existing system to do this. You can create an extension for MediaWiki to do this without *too* much trouble. Basing it off an [existing extension](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension_Matrix/user_identity) is probably a good starting point. By looking at [AuthJoomla](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension%3aAuthJoomla), [AuthBugzilla](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension%3aAuthBugzilla) and [AuthSymfony](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension%3aAuthSymfony) you should get a good idea of how MediaWiki's authentication extension API operates. It's really just a matter of creating the class, getting it to call the relevant UC functions and then loading it as an extension into MW.

Having said that, UserCake seems unmaintained. It may be worth taking this opportunity to migrate your users to another authentication system. If you are using credentials between several applications you might want to look at something like LDAP.

Answer (score 1):

I know that this is a really old question, but UserSpice is the fully PDO/OOP spiritual successor to UserCake and would probably be better equipped to handle this.  It would take some modification, but it could be done.

Answer (score 0):

May I recommend that you use other ways to secure you applications. Take a look at Windows Azure ACS that gives you security federation to Facebook, Google, Yahoo and more.

This allows you to focus on your application and not security protocols.

Azure ACS supports many different of protocols and works great with PHP as well as .Net based applications.

I did a quick search and found the http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:OpenID that can use Azure ACS. (Access Control Services)

There are other alternatives to ACS such as Ping Identity and OpenSSO; But ACS is a cheap alternative to Ping.